# dynamically assign dataframe name from previous list

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, selenium

I have created a loop that looks up some information from some government websites and want to add the list item to be part of the states dataframe name so that I can later append the states together.

here is my code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    import pandas as pd
    import time
    from urllib.request import urlopen 
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    import requests
    import lxml.html as lh
    from itertools import product
    
    
    states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia",
    "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", 
    "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire",
    "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
    "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", 
    "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]

period = "2020"

for state in states:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:/webdrivers/chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get('https://www.nbc.gov/pilt/counties.cfm')
    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    state_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'state_code')
    drp = Select(state_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(state)
    year_s = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'fiscal_yr')
    drp = Select(year_s)
    drp.select_by_visible_text(period)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    link = driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'Search')
    link.click()
    addrss = driver.current_url
    
    states[state].df = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
        
    states[state].df['YEAR'] = period
    states[state].df['STATE'] = state
    
    
    states[state].df['PAYMENT'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT'].str.replace(r'\W','')
    states[state].df['PAYMENT'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT'].astype(int)
    
    states[state].df['PAYMENT.1'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT.1'].str.replace(r'\W','')
    states[state].df['PAYMENT.1'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT.1'].astype(int)
    
    states[state].df['PAYMENT.2'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT.2'].str.replace(r'\W','')
    states[state].df['PAYMENT.2'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT.2'].astype(int)
    
    states[state].df['PILT/ACRE'] = states[state].df['PAYMENT']/states[state].df['TOTAL ACRES']
    
       
states[]
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8ecfd06b8bbf> in <module>
     17     addrss = driver.current_url
     18 
---> 19     states[i].df = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
     20 
     21     states[i].df['YEAR'] = period

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'df'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I get a different error: `states[state].df = pd.read_html(addrss)[2]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: You are passing a str

Comment: Yes I get that error too but how do I pass those to become part of the df name?

Comment: You need to take some time to reduce this down to an [mcve]. This doesn't have anything to do with Selenium and having that in there just makes it more complicated and harder to see the actual problem. Your issue is how you are trying to add data to a dataframe that doesn't exist because you haven't created it yet. Do a super simple example... take your `states` list and create a dataframe from that. There are numerous examples on the web, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-a-pandas-dataframe-from-lists/. Then start adding in code until it stops working.